# Issue installing "devtools" package in R-studio

Tags: r, installation, package

> I have tried for hours now to install the "devtools" package. Each time it returns me with multiple errors. Initially I did not have admin permissions to install it, so I ran as administrator and it finally attempts to install the package. What returns is a series of errors like so:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘gh’, ‘openssl’, ‘usethis’, ‘covr’, ‘httr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gh_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 29043 bytes (28 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 28 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1204168 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.6.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 254833 bytes (248 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 248 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/covr_3.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 146686 bytes (143 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 143 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 159950 bytes (156 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 156 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 373604 bytes (364 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 364 KB

* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Thu Sep 17 16:33:13 CDT 2020: Auto-brewing openssl@1.1 in /private/tmp/RtmpdX1qXS/R.INSTALLbd2c2e4d6828/.autobrew/build-openssl@1.1...
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/private/tmp/RtmpdX1qXS/R.INSTALLbd2c2e4d6828/.autobrew/build-openssl@1.1/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/private/tmp/RtmpdX1qXS/R.INSTALLbd2c2e4d6828/.autobrew/build-openssl@1.1/opt/openssl/include
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
tools/version.c:1:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘gh’
* removing ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library/gh’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gh’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘covr’
* removing ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library/covr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gh’ is not available for package ‘usethis’
* removing ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library/usethis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘usethis’, ‘covr’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Users/ajadams968/R/library/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/tmp/RtmpuFBrkf/downloaded_packages’
```

> I have also tried installing the dependencies individually, but the "openssl" package refuses to install. I have a feeling that the entire issue is the dependencies not installing, but I don't know how to fix that issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read and heed the advice in the error text there? *"Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)"*

Comment: What OS are you running? How did you install R in the first place?

Comment: In that sentence, it references "openssl was not found" because the OS package 'openssl' was not found, not to be confused here with the R package 'openssl'.

Comment: When you say you've tried installing openssl, did you do so from R, or from the command line? And did you try installing openssl, or openssl-dev?

Answer (score 0):

The package installation worked after I fresh installed with R, so perhaps my previous installation was causing the issue. Thanks fo your assistance.